# Why is component rendered as input when bound to a bean, in Read mode?

Tags: xpages

I have a field component in a Xpage bound to a bean.
When creating documents the field is rendered as an input field but when reading a document the component is also rendered as an input field, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the bean has a getter and a **setter** for the component then it gets rendered as input field.

Use the input field's property `readonly` to determine if it should be rendered as input field or as a readonly text field.

```xml
    <xp:inputText
        id="inputText1"
        readonly="#{myBean.readOnly}"
        value="#{myBean.myField}">
    </xp:inputText>
```

If you have several fields bound to the bean then surround them by a panel with the property `readonly`.  This way you don't need to set this property to every field.

Comment: Thx, that fixed that problem. Next thing is why values are from bean and not from document, in my case they are empty. Does a bean override all "normal" connectivity between the xpage and the backend?

Comment: @MikaelGrevsten, if you bind the field to a bean - then that is what you get. So you would need to read your document's values into that bean (or provide a mechanism to look up the value on request - from the document). This is the real force of using beans as it allows you to create a true MVC pattern and have a loose coupling between the data and the presentation ;-)

Comment: @JohnDalsgaard so when using beans in Xpage you override all defaults and has to create logic for handling the connection between backend? I noticed that when saving, I had to manually set the field value from QS…

Comment: @MikaelGrevsten, well, that is really what you ask for if you bind the field to a bean property - instead of a document. But as mentioned, that really gives you many new possibilities... See e.g. these slides: http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/mvc-and-xpages/

Comment: Mikael - If you want further information or examples of beans theres been several videos on NotesIn9.com and I'm currently running a series that will be very "bean heavy" in the next couple of episodes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to a `isReadOnly(Object key)` method to your bean that handles whether the bean is readonly or not. The isreadOnly() method can base its logic on for instance the action parameter. Here's a simplified example:

```
public boolean isReadOnly(final Object key) {
    String action = ExtLibUtil.readParameter(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "action");
    if ("editdocument".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The controls will then automatically use this to determine whether an inputText control for instance needs to be displayed in readmode or editmode.

Comment: Per - I get the concept of what you're doing - though when I use beans I typically create my own URL's rather then the XPages generated "editdocument" - BUT what is the final Object key parameter you're passing in for?  It doesn't look like you're using that?  thx

Comment: David, my impression is that this is the method signature that you need to implement. But I might be wrong. I've seen it used by (thr great) Tim Tripcony in his How Ya Bean project: https://bitbucket.org/timtripcony/howyabean

Comment: I have decided to have two different XPages for view and edit (and separate managed beans) since there is a LOT of extra things going on in edit mode (validation, lookups, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Per.  hmm interesting...

John - I've not done different beans for View and Edit - that seems odd to me.  I have embraced Jesse's page controllers and that seems to me a good place for some of the logic that might not fit nicely in an bean that's representing a document.